# Cannot update / insert or delete on "live" mySQL database on cPanel

Tags: mysql, node.js, cpanel

I have a mySQL database that my app uses. On my local machine I can do anything and the user in the connection string has all privelages. As does the user (same user) on my database with my hosting company.

I have set it up exactly the same with my hosting provider. When I connect to my live app it connects perfectly to the database. I can query the database fine but I cannot add add, amend or delete records.

My service providor suggested I optimize the tables in the database but that has not made any difference whatsoever.

My app is a node app and I am using the mysql package.

I am very confused and apparantly so is my service providor as now 18 or so hours later this issue has not been solved.

Originally it was suggested to use remote MySQL on cPanel but I am not trying to connect from another program like workbench or anything. I simply want my web app to be able to amend the records in the database - no matter where the user is located or regardless of their ip address.

my connection string is as follows (on both local and live apps)

```
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
user: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
multipleStatements: true //for more than one query in a get route
});
```

Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

[image: user prevelages]

Comment: Hi Wayne, this really seems to be a Grant issue. Can you post the grants for this user here?

Comment: Hi nicolas, added image as per your question

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: Mostly nothing - on some screens I get "Incomplete response received from application"

Comment: There should error with error code find it.

Comment: Hi Sumesh, no error code whatsover, thats all it says on the screen

Comment: Is there `phpmyadmin` in cpanel.

Comment: yes there is. Thats where I tried to optimize the tables

Comment: Try insert ,delete record from `phpmyadmin`. If it works no issue with provider and check mysql versions too.

Comment: Hi, deleted a record but interesting thing is it is dissapearing off the database but stays visible on my app

Comment: Your app accessing data from somewhere else. Check your configuration properly. I think your app accessing from dev server not from live server

Comment: As Sumesh pointed, you must have a more complete log in your server, do you have access to it? Can you describe your complete stack too?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that phpmyAdmin, the table names is case sensitive. I had my data manipulation query table names in upper case